# Compared to Windows, my Ubuntu is blurry and has limited color range for blacks

Tags: nvidia, fonts, display-resolution

Not sure how to fix this, I have searched everywhere to not avail.

I dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu - in other words both operating systems use the same monitor and NVIDIA graphics card. I can't even bring myself to use Ubuntu because of two problems:

1. Everything is blurry compared to Windows. I am running at the right resolution 1920x1080, and font settings are slight aliasing with RGB. But all the fonts look worse, especially in the browser (Firefox).
2. On Windows there is a range of colors for blacks from dark grey to pure black. On Ubuntu, there is only one: pure black, and it's painful to look at! Again it's the worst in the browser. I think this one has something to do with the NVIDIA card because I have another laptop that runs Ubuntu just fine and displays the same black color range as Windows. I am using the proprietary graphics driver.

I tried installing Xubuntu instead (basically Ubuntu with XFCE) but I still have this problem.

Does anyone have similar problems or know how to fix this? Have I not installed the right fonts?

Comment: I've similar problem. My fonts are okay, I'm using Fira Code for most of the things. But every image/video when ever there is anything black, it just looks pixelated. I also have dual boot setup and NVIDIA card. I tried increasing brightness from nvidia-settings, it helps a little but that doesn't fix the root cause of the issue.